# How do I import pcap or pyshark on python

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, capture, ethernet

I want to write the Ethernet packets capture while using python.
I googling and found that I should using Pcap library or PyShark but I try to import pcap, it said that can not found module name Pcap, so I try to using PyShark instance but it show like this on Python shell

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyshark
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyshark-0.3.3-py2.7.egg\pyshark\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyshark.capture.live_capture import LiveCapture
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyshark-0.3.3-py2.7.egg\pyshark\capture\live_capture.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyshark.capture.capture import Capture
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyshark-0.3.3-py2.7.egg\pyshark\capture\capture.py", line 7, in <module>
    import trollius as asyncio
ImportError: No module named trollius
```

About this problem, what should I do?
How can I import the library to python?

OS is Windows 8.1 and Python version 2.7.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pyshark` project requires that [`trollius`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trollius) is installed for Python versions before Python 3.4. You'll need to install that separately.

It *should* have been installed when you installed the `pyshark` package however. Make sure to always use a tool like `pip` to install your packages and dependencies like these are taken care of automatically; the `pyshark` project [declares the dependencies correctly](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark/blob/master/src/setup.py#L12):

```
install_requires=['lxml', 'py', 'trollius', 'logbook'],
```

Comment: @Cashchii: Since this is Python 2.7.9, you can use `python -m pip install trollius`. For installing wheels, you first need to install the `wheel` support: `python -m pip install wheel`

Comment: I try to install 'trollius' but it shown like this picture >> https://www.dropbox.com/s/3sx08um4jyq208v/Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: I tried to install pip and then install pycap but I got like this picture https://www.dropbox.com/s/sgb3c3z216fl8yn/Untitled.png?dl=0 , what does it mean? I'm not sure about it .

Comment: @Cashchii: that library is trying to compile a C extension and cannot find the header file needed to compile.

Comment: @Cashchii: there are [installation instructions](https://code.google.com/p/pypcap/source/browse/trunk/INSTALL) in the project repository. To compile on Windows, you'll need a compiler (Microsoft Visual Studio compatible with the Python version) and *winpcap with development headers*.